# HTML Table Content Breaking Word Into New Line

Tags: html, html-table, word-wrap, word-break

I'm creating a PDF from HTML that contains a table of data. When the PDF is generated, content from some table columns (header and otherwise) is wrapped into a new line, not by white space, but words are broken into new lines. For example, "Claims Year" is the name of one of my column heads, but on the PDF, the column heading is displayed in two lines as

Claim
s Year

A similar thing happens with multiple other cells in the table but not all. How can I get it to not do this, preferably by allowing the column to stretch and encapsulate the words (at least have Claims in one line and Year in the next, doesn't have to be Claims Year in one line)

Comment: How are you creating the pdf? Do you have JavaScript code to do it?

Comment: iTextSharp library in C#

Comment: in short i'd want for the table columns to never break a word into a new line, it can do a new line after a space, but never to break a word into two